# Insert inlined images on Gmail app

Tags: gmail

I tried using the attached image option and thought I would be able to drag the image into place but this didn't work.

Is it possible to do insert inlined images directly on Gmail?

Answer (score 21):

Workaround:

1. Open Google Docs
2. Open a new Word document
3. Select "Insert image" and insert the image of your choice
4. Once done, it is now in clipboard form, copy that
5. Switch to Gmail and paste the image

Comment: It looks like this adds a full-size copy of the image which is unfortunate.

Comment: Also, it seems it's limited to one image only. Cannot paste any other pic past the first one. Nice hack though

Comment: Nice hack! @wp78de if you want to reduce the size, try making a screenshot of the original image, and cropping the screenshot, then insert the screenshot in Google Docs. They are usually smaller than original (albeit lower quality). But if that's not good enough, you'll need a photo resizer app to adjust the original image's dimensions and file size.

Comment: @Ozh I could insert a second image. Try again. Also if you're having problems copy-pasting only the image (like, it's showing up blank), add some text near the image in Google Docs, and copy-paste both the image and text together. Then just delete the extra text in Gmail. (As with any hack, this needs some getting used to.)

Answer (score 7):

To send a photo on Gmail using the Android app:

1. Save the photo that you want to send to a local folder on your phone.
2. While composing a message or reply, tap the attachment paperclip icon () at the top of the Gmail app and select "Attach file" from the menu that appears.

   [image]
3. Select the photo that you want to send from a local folder on your phone. This photo is sent inline. If you selected a photo from anywhere else except for a local folder on your phone it would be sent as an attachment instead of inline.

Comment: When I do this, the image is sent as an attachment, not inline. You mention "by default"... is there an option to change this behavior somewhere?

Comment: @JasonC If you select the *Attach file* option and select a file from a local folder on your phone it is sent inline by default. If you select the *Attach file* option and select a file from anywhere else it is sent as an attachment by default.

Comment: ^ this doesn't work for me ... still attaches rather than inline after trying with multiple different folders on local drive on Pixel 3 Android OS 12. Notice I cant put text below the image and it has a box with image size etc listed in interface, indicating it is indeed an attachment

Comment: @watsonic I'm still running Android 11 on my phone. I'll re-edit after I upgrade it to Android 12.

Comment: This method does not work for me. Oneplus 7 Pro, Android 11.